# How to I can custom exception message from FileInterceptor?

Tags: file, upload, nestjs, interceptor

I want custom exception from FileInterceptor. 
Here my lines of code:

```
 @Post('single')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', { limits: {
      files: 1
    }}),
  )
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file, @GetUser('id') userId: number, @Body() dto) {
    this.logger.log('Upload file');
    file.createdBy = userId;
    file.oldFileName = dto.oldFileName;
    return this.client.send('upload_file', file);
  }
```

I pass in body with file attribute, it is 1 array files (there are 2 files) 
I got message:

```
{
    "response": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "message": "Too many files",
        "error": "Bad Request"
    },
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Too many files",
    "name": "BadRequestException"
}
```

I want custom that message like to this:

```
{
     "code": 400,
    "message": "Too many files"
}
```

Please help me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1) to custom your error